# Mixing keywords match types in Google Adwords

Tags: advertising, keywords, google-ads

Using Google Adwords:

**Q#1.** Can someone use a mix of match types in keywords?
For example, can someone use the keyword `[large size] +leather "black shoes" from Atlantis`, thus using exact, modified broad match, phrase match and broad match in a single keyword?

**Q#2.** If the above functionality is indeed supported, does anybody know what effects it has on an ad's performance to mix keyword match types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix match types in Google Adwords.   You will need to bid on multiple exact match keywords to get the coverage that you want:

- large leather black shoes
- size 12 atlantis black shoes
- size 13 leather black shoes
- ...

Use the [Google Adwords Keyword Tools](https://adwords.google.com/o/KeywordTool) to vet the phrases and only bid on the ones that have any volume.